# Redmine - docker version problem with sending mail

Tags: docker, email, send, redmine

i've a problem with my docker istance of redmine.
All works fine eccepts for the email sender.

I've created a new configuration.yml:

```
email_delivery:
delivery_method: :smtp
smtp_settings:
  enable_starttls_auto: true
  ssl: true
  address: example@mydomain.com
  port: 465
  authentication: :plain
  domain: 'mydomain.com'
  user_name: 'example@mydomain.comt'
  password: 'password'
```

But i can't send email, in the logs i can see this error:

```
    I, [2021-10-11T11:23:49.199903 #1]  INFO -- :   Rendered issues/_action_menu.html.erb (4.7ms)
I, [2021-10-11T11:23:49.216825 #1]  INFO -- :   Rendering mailer/issue_edit.text.erb within layouts/mailer
I, [2021-10-11T11:23:49.219989 #1]  INFO -- :   Rendered issue_relations/_form.html.erb (0.9ms)
I, [2021-10-11T11:23:49.220134 #1]  INFO -- :   Rendered issues/_relations.html.erb (1.3ms)
I, [2021-10-11T11:23:49.226888 #1]  INFO -- :   Rendered issues/tabs/_history.html.erb (6.2ms)
I, [2021-10-11T11:23:49.226962 #1]  INFO -- :   Rendered common/_tabs.html.erb (6.7ms)
I, [2021-10-11T11:23:49.228740 #1]  INFO -- :   Rendered issues/_action_menu.html.erb (1.6ms)
I, [2021-10-11T11:23:49.237345 #1]  INFO -- :   Rendered issues/_trackers_description.html.erb (0.3ms)
I, [2021-10-11T11:23:49.243580 #1]  INFO -- :   Rendered mailer/_issue.text.erb (26.3ms)
I, [2021-10-11T11:23:49.243686 #1]  INFO -- :   Rendered mailer/issue_edit.text.erb within layouts/mailer (26.8ms)
I, [2021-10-11T11:23:49.244331 #1]  INFO -- :   Rendering mailer/issue_edit.html.erb within layouts/mailer
I, [2021-10-11T11:23:49.251245 #1]  INFO -- :   Rendered mailer/_issue.html.erb (2.3ms)
I, [2021-10-11T11:23:49.251366 #1]  INFO -- :   Rendered mailer/issue_edit.html.erb within layouts/mailer (6.9ms)
E, [2021-10-11T11:23:49.263689 #1] ERROR -- : Email delivery error: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
I, [2021-10-11T11:23:49.263774 #1]  INFO -- : Performed ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: bafe66f3-6335-4c9b-9fab-f9257c808360) from Async(mailers) in 65.5ms
I, [2021-10-11T11:23:49.276232 #1]  INFO -- :   Rendered issues/_form_custom_fields.html.erb (0.1ms)
I, [2021-10-11T11:23:49.276484 #1]  INFO -- :   Rendered issues/_attributes.html.erb (38.1ms)
I, [2021-10-11T11:23:49.277168 #1]  INFO -- :   Rendered issues/_form.html.erb (48.0ms)
I, [2021-10-11T11:23:49.286616 #1]  INFO -- :   Rendered attachments/_form.html.erb (1.5ms)
I, [2021-10-11T11:23:49.288190 #1]  INFO -- :   Rendered issues/_edit.html.erb (59.3ms)
I, [2021-10-11T11:23:49.288238 #1]  INFO -- :   Rendered issues/_action_menu_edit.html.erb (61.2ms)
I, [2021-10-11T11:23:49.292637 #1]  INFO -- :   Rendered issues/_sidebar.html.erb (2.7ms)
I, [2021-10-11T11:23:49.295925 #1]  INFO -- :   Rendered watchers/_watchers.html.erb (3.2ms)
I, [2021-10-11T11:23:49.296376 #1]  INFO -- :   Rendered issues/show.html.erb within layouts/base (101.3ms)
```

i don't understand what is the problem

Docker version 20.10.7, build 20.10.7-0ubuntu1~20.04.2
Redmine 4.2.2.stable
image latest stable

Thanks all

Comment: Why would it be related to your Docker version ? The container logs come from the image's entrypoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `address` field in your `configuration.yml` has to contain the server hostname where Redmine sends mail to for further delivery, e.g. `smtp.example.com`.

It does not contain however the sender email address. This email address in configured from inside Redmine at *Administration* -> *Settings*.

Please also make sure to follow correct indentation of your YAML file as leading whitespace is semantically important in YAML. Some examples can be found at https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/emailconfiguration.

Comment: omg mate, you've right!! is my mistake.... thank you very much... (i'm not blind, only stupid XD)

Comment: I my answer helped you solve your question, you may consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: sure mate, thank you